# Remove extra _ from mask

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

Both that inputs are valid:

```
(00)0000-0000
(00)10000-0000
```

so I'm using this mask:

```
(00)90000-0000
```

as one of the digits after `(00)` is optional it can have either 8 or 9 digits. But if the input has 8 digits, the MaskTextBox show an extra `_` in the end, like this `(00)0000-0000_` but as that's of the optional digit, I'd like to remove it. If it has 8 or 9 digits must be show as `(00)0000-0000` or `(00)00000-0000` respectively. I hope it's clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the TextChanged event to change the PropmtChar property according to the MaskCompleted property:

```
private void MaskedTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MaskedTextBox1.PromptChar = (MaskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted) ? ' ' : '_' ;
}
```

Comment: I like it... show the extra(s) `_` to the user may be annoying. For example, I also the phone number (the one in the question) I have another which must accept only digits from 1 to n, so I had the mask `09999` where all the optional digits became `_`, the digits mixed with the `_` would confuse the user. As a empty character literal doesn't exists in C# we should use a white-space. For this specific case, I'm using this code: `if (MaskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted)
            {
              MaskedTextBox1.PromptChar = ' ';
               MaskedTextBox1Text = n_textBox.Text.Trim();
            }`

Comment: that way the maskTextBox accepts only digits with optional ones and doesn't show any `_` :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here... How i solved? used 2 text-boxes and treated the case where the user "backspace" from the 2nd to the first...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Zohar Peled's approach is good it doesn't need to add another TextBox (this is a hack, haha :) ) and the solution in my comments on Zohar Peled's deal with the white spaces. It can for example, mark the ´MaskedTextBox` accepts only digits with optional ones and doesn't show any extra `_` (what the optional digits became) by removing them in the `TextChanged` event when `MaskedTextBox`'s job is done.